# Add points at specific gps coordinates in qgis

Tags: qgis, gps, coordinates

I created a layer in order to draw points with the azimut and distance plugin. IT didnt work at all. There was not even 1 point created. I followed the tutorial here: http://www.teuderun.de/workshops/qgis/aufschlusspunkte-hinzuf%C3%BCgen/

I entered the gps data in decimal format as suggested in the tutorial.
There is no draw button. No points are drawn. The layer is in active mode.

Are there any other options to draw a few points using their coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem:

I made a txt file with the information of the coordinates and changed the coordinate system to GK.

Then I imported the txt file and now I have my desired points :-)